# If you use new to allocate space, when must you free it?

Tags: c++, unix, data-structures, binary-tree, nodes

We created the binary tree structures in class which used new to create tnodes. I have to write freetree function for it.

I just have general question. If you use new to allocate space, when must you free it?

Comment: If you need help learning language basics, stackoverflow.com is probably not the place to learn them.  Your book and or teacher should have gone over this exact detail quite thoroughly.

Comment: Use smart pointers and you don't have to worry about memory lifetime

Comment: In your case, (barring the raii and smart pointer mantras which i fully support but am near-sure your instructor will NOT let you use) you need a special POSTorder enumeration that frees the current node pointer **after** calling the same POSTorder function (iow. recursively) on its children. This will free every node only after freeing any children of that node, with the root node being the final victim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't need the allocated space anymore.

```
struct Data { ... }

...

Data* data{new Data};
data->something();
doSomethingWithDataPtr(data);

delete data;
```

Obviously this example is very simple, but deciding when to `delete` allocated space is completely subjective... just make sure you eventually delete it. (Consider using smart pointers instead of `new` and `delete` to avoid mistakes).